# background image will not be equal on the second page

Tags: html, css

I have a multi-page website on which I have a header, that is equal to all of the sub-sites (only the background-image / some text changes). For this I have 1 css file and to change background-image on each site I just overwrite it with css.

```
.hero-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 70rem;
    width: 60%;
    background: url(../images/others/main-stomatologie.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}

.hero-img.stomatology{
    background: url(../images/others/main-stomatologie.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Buut the problem is that if I use it this way, the image is bigger by 5% lets say, but I have no clue why. I have found out that if I dont use the class stomatology and I change the background manualy in dev tools it works. Can someone say why is the image not equal?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved it by changing background-image: url( ... ) instead of background: .. .
Still its weird

```
.hero-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 70rem;
    width: 60%;
    background: no-repeat top left;
    background-image: url(../images/others/main.png) ;
    background-size: cover;
}

.hero-img.stomatologie{
    background-image: url(../images/others/main-stomatologie.png) ;
}
```